# Giving error for dynamic id generation

Tags: angular

**Error:**

> EXCEPTION: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'target' since it
>   isn't a known native property ("
>                     ]data-target="{{ supplier.entityid }}">
>                         Company

**code:**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="{{ supplier.entityid }}">
                        Company
                    </button>
```

I was trying to generate a pop up window using a dynamic id but its giving an error. I do not understand why its giving an error? Is there any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use this syntax:

```
<xx [attr.data-target]="supplier.entityid"></xx>
```